# How to use "COLLATE AS" with Sequel and Ruby

Tags: ruby, sequel, collate

When using Sequel, is it possible to produce a "SQL WHERE" clause that contains "COLLATE AS?":

```
ColumnName COLLATE Latin1_General_CS_AS
```

If not, then what can I use to do this?

I  searched through the Sequel documentation and Stack Overflow and this has not been mentioned there.

Comment: We'd like to see where you searched, and what else you tried. Sequel is well documented.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Sequel doesn't have direct support for `COLLATE`, so you have to use literal SQL for that part:

`where(Sequel.lit('? COLLATE Latin1_General_CS_AS', :ColumnName))`